# How Can I create method which use Java generics put the maps key to list?

Tags: java

```
public <T> List<T> map2list(Map<T, T> map){

    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>(map.keySet());
    return list;

}
```

My Method like this... But it does not work.

Comment: If My Map like this:   Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();    the method does not work....

Comment: Well yeah, how do you expect `T` to be a string and an integer at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your map is empty, because the example below works:

```
public class Utils {

    public <T, K> List<T> map2list(Map<T, K> map) {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>(map.keySet());
        return list;
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        map.put("test1", 1);
        map.put("test2", 2);
        map.put("test3", 3);
        Utils t = new Utils();
        List<String> result = t.map2list(map);
        for (String key : result) {
            System.out.println(key);
        }
    }

}
```

printing the following:

> test2
>   test3
>   test1

Comment: Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        map.put("test1", 1);
        map.put("test2", 2);
        map.put("test3",3);

        Utils t = new Utils();
        List<String> result = t.map2list(map);
        for (String key : result) {
            System.out.println(key);
        }

Comment: fixed it according to your comment

Comment: As a stateless utility class method, `map2list` should be `static`.

Answer (score 0):

If your map in argument is of `String` as key & `Integer` as value, try following method,

```
public static <T, L> List<T> map2list (Map<T, L> map) {  
     List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>(map.keySet());  
     return list;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<T>` define only one type for the runtime type-aguments of your map. So if you have different types of arguments for the generics of your map, you can change it like this by defining two generic type T and for example K:

```
public static <T,K> List<T> map2list(Map<T, K> map){
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>(map.keySet());
    return list;
}
```

And it will work.

Also this situation supports that if you want to pass `Map<String,String>` or generally `Map<T,T>` too.

Hope this would help.

Comment: Your welcome. In this site usually you can check an answer as the answer of your question by checking the green check mark at the left of the desired answer.